# Two function template candidates. After making one argument a reference, the less specialized template gets chosen

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

I have common code – Dijkstra's algorithm – I use in different contexts, so I decided to use tag dispatch.

The common code is in the following function (you can see `End` get dispatched depending on the Tag template parameter):

```
template <typename Tag, typename ... Args>
void Dijkstra(blahblah, Args&&... arg) {
...
    if (End(Tag(), cost, n_id, distances, time_limit, args ...)) {
            break;
    }
```

For most of the contexts I define a default no-op as follows:

```
template<typename ... Args>
bool inline End(Args&& ...) {
    return false;
}
```

For one context I define the function with the following signature:

```
bool inline End(OneContextTag, Duration d, NodeId n_id, Distances distances, Du time_limit, blahblah) {
```

Everything worked as expected, till I found I forgot `&` in the signature after `Distances` – I was copying Distances, a large unordered_map, every time.

However, after I changed it to `const Distances&` to avoid expensive copying, the less specialized noop version got called. I have no idea why. And how to fix it.

(I swear the change is only in adding a single character `&`. Or `const&`)

(The signature is otherwise correct, if I comment out the generic noop version, it just uses the `OneContextTag` version.)

(The code is more complex, but I hope it can be figured out from this.)

Comment: Hm ... [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/E3X4FI) ... also please make a minimal reproducible example from this ... look at my code in the link, that's 1 minute effort which makes the question so much better ..

Comment: @DanielJour If you use `const int&` it will prefer the template here, since it's an exact match. [example](https://ideone.com/7slWnN)

Comment: Ah .. ok .. [can reproduce](https://ideone.com/awQfUb) when I use a rvalue ... but you're not forwarding `distances` ... so this shouldn't happen in your case?

Comment: @DanielJour I'm not

Comment: @Adam .. please try to make a compileable example ... at least we need to see the arguments you pass to `End`

Comment: @super it does it even if adding just `&`, unlike the example. I'll notify you if I manage to do MVP.

Comment: @Adam What works and not depends on how you call the function. More precicely in this case if `Distance` is cv-qualified and what value category it is (rvalue/lvalue). For example passing a non-const lvalue will have the template version dedude `Distance&`, so in that case the non-template version needs to use exactly `Distance&` and not `Distance&&` or `const Distance&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have an answer to why overload resolution works the way it does here atm.  But I have a potential solution for you, which is also (IMO) more robust:

Change the default `End` to accept a `UseDefaultEnd` tag as the first parameter.  For each context which should use the default `End`, subclass its tag from `UseDefaultEnd`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct UseDefaultEnd {};

/* Comment first parameter; then you get the same behavior as 
   you're currently trying to solve. */
template<typename ... Args>
bool inline End(UseDefaultEnd, Args&& ...) {
// bool inline End(Args&& ...) {
    return false;
}

struct OneTag {};

struct OtherTag : public UseDefaultEnd {};

bool inline End(OneTag, int const & i) {
    return true;
}

template<typename Tag>
void Caller() {
    int i = 42;
    if (End(Tag(), i)) {
        std::cout << "Used specific version of End" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    Caller<OtherTag>();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    Caller<OneTag>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So what you're asking about is basically why the following program prints `Special foo` but `Generic bar`:

```
struct A {};

template<class ... Args>
void foo(Args&&...)
{
    std::cout << "Generic foo\n";
}

void foo(A)
{
    std::cout << "Special foo\n";
}

template<class ... Args>
void bar(Args&&...)
{
    std::cout << "Generic bar\n";
}

void bar(A const&)
{
    std::cout << "Special bar\n";
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo(a);
    bar(a);
}
```

Let's look at what happens for overload resolution:

#### 1. Candidate functions are selected.

> `C++11/[over.match.funcs]/7` In each case where a candidate is a function template, candidate function template specializations are generated using template argument deduction (14.8.3, 14.8.2). Those candidates are then handled as candidate functions in the usual way.

Candidates for call to `foo(a)`:

```
template<> void foo<A&>(A&); // reference collapsing
void foo(A);
```

Candidates for call to `bar(a)`:

```
template<> void bar<A&>(A&); 
void bar(A const&);
```

#### 2. Select of best viable function:

In the first place, an overload is better if (at least) one of the parameters has a better conversion sequence (and no other has a worse conversion sequence).

> `C++11/[over.ics.rank]/3` Standard conversion sequence **S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if** [ ... ] S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and **the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more cv-qualified** than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers.

This results in the preference of the template candidate for `bar` since the conversion required to call `void bar(A const&)` requires binding an lvalue to an more cv-qualified const lvalue reference.
*Therefore, you see the generic version called when using `Distances const&`.*

> `C++11/[over.best.ics]/6` When the parameter type is not a reference [ ... ]
>   When the parameter has a class type and the argument expression has the same type, the implicit conversion sequence is an identity conversion.

This makes the conversion sequence for the parameter `a` when passed to `void foo(A)` an identity conversion (which is also the case for the template function).

If neither of the overloads has a better conversion sequence, then the non-template version wins over the template.

> `C++11/[over.match.best]/1` [ ... ] Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if [ ... ] F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization.

This is the case for `foo` and makes your code behave as you intended when you use `Distances distances`.